# Why does my Microsoft Habu force me to unplug and replug in when booting up?

Tags: windows-7, usb, mouse

I'm not too sure why, but every single time I boot my computer, I have to unplug and replug my semi-new Microsoft Habu, when I use Windows 7. Why does it do this? I've been through my BIOS, msconfig, and what-not.. It just seems to happen all the time.

I've even looked in forums, with people resorting to changing their mouse because of the same issue.. It's stupid.

Hopefully someone else can help... hopefully someone with experience with this mouse.

Answer (score 1):

It could be you will have to update the firmware to fix this problem

[Follow these Microsoft instructions](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/930616) to see if it helps

Here's [another guide](http://forums.extremeoverclocking.com/showthread.php?t=246317) that has some more images to guide you